# Memory Corruption Due to Copy Constructor/Deleting Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memcpy

I have a struct called SFrame which contains many elements, notably 2 elements which are of type unsigned char*. I create a member variable of this struct in my class but I newly initialize it on each iteration in a function in my class (except for when a certain boolean is true). I do this in the following manner:

```
if (false == m_bRemainderNeedsProcessing)
{
    // ... calls before and after the initialization are unimportant and not shown
    m_sFrame = SFrame();
}
```

Then I pass m_sFrame to a function to assign some of its elements and then I need to assign an unsigned char array to my pszMessage variable in my struct.

```
            m_sFrame.iMessageSize = m_sFrame.iPayloadLength;
            m_sFrame.iOriginalMessageSize = m_sFrame.iPayloadLength;
            m_sFrame.pszMessage = new unsigned char[m_sFrame.iPayloadLength + Constants::RSSL_DECODE_PADDING];
            m_sFrame.pszOriginalMessage = new unsigned char[m_sFrame.iPayloadLength + Constants::RSSL_DECODE_PADDING];
```

These SFrame instances are stored in a vector of SFrames i.e.

```
std::vector<SFrame>;
```

I want to be able to reuse m_sFrame for each iteration but I have to ensure that if I am going to clear the contents of the SFrame, that when I store it inside the vector, the SFrame is copied into the vector without losing it's assigned values. For this I create a copy constructor for SFrame:

I have attached an image of part of the SFrame's copy constructor.

At the end of my function, I clear the memory in the pszMessage (and the pszOriginalMessage which is almost the same) by doing the following:

```
ClearMemory(m_sFrame.pszMessage);
```

Where the ClearMemory function does the following:

```
void CPCAPParser::ClearMemory(unsigned char *pszBuffer)
{
    if(pszBuffer != NULL)
    {
        delete [] pszBuffer;
    }
}
```

Thee problem is, this function seems to be deleting more than it should do.... because after many iterations, I get an unhandled exception: Access Violation...

I've attached a few images that might help convey what the problem is. Really need help with this :(, if anyone needs me to add more details let me know.

Thanks

http://imageshack.com/f/pduGDLGZp (Constants::RSSL_DECODE_PADDING has length 7 so there are 13 bytes in total which have been set - made evident at the start of the memory block).

http://imageshack.com/f/exRaaEmip - Where I am calling ClearMemory (the memory address is obviously still the same).

I would post more images but I don't have enough rep...

SFrame:

```
struct SFrame
{
    int* ipTemp_int_ptr;
    int* ipTemp_int_ptr_actual;
    int* piTimestampPos;
    int* piOffset;
    int iIP_Header_Length;
    int iTCP_Header_Length;
    int iTCP_Source_Port;
    int iTCP_Dest_Port;
    long long uiSequenceNumber;
    long long uiInitialSequenceNumber;
    long long uiAckNumber;
    int iIp_total_length;
    int iActual_frame_length;
    int iOriginal_frame_length;
    int iCaptured_frame_length;
    int iTotalPayloadLength;
    int iTotalMsgLoad;
    int iPayloadLength;
    int iBytesComplete;
    int iFragmentID;
    int iRemainder;
    int iMessageSize;
    int iOriginalMessageSize;
    long long iNextExpectedSequenceNum;
    std::string strSourceAddress;
    std::string strDestAddress;
    std::string strTimestamp;
    unsigned char* pszMessage;
    unsigned char* pszOriginalMessage;
    unsigned int uiClientID;
    int iStartOfRemainder;
    int iAccumulatedMsgLength;

    SFrame() : ipTemp_int_ptr ( NULL ),
        ipTemp_int_ptr_actual ( NULL ),
        piTimestampPos ( NULL ),
        piOffset ( NULL ),
        pszMessage ( NULL ),
        pszOriginalMessage ( NULL ),
        iIP_Header_Length( 0 ),
        iTCP_Header_Length ( 0 ),
        iTCP_Source_Port ( 0 ),
        iTCP_Dest_Port ( 0 ),
        iIp_total_length ( 0 ),
        iActual_frame_length ( 0 ),
        iOriginal_frame_length ( 0 ),
        iCaptured_frame_length ( 0 ),
        uiSequenceNumber( 0 ),
        uiInitialSequenceNumber ( 0 ),
        uiAckNumber( 0 ),
        iPayloadLength ( 0 ),
        iNextExpectedSequenceNum ( 0 ),
        uiClientID ( 0 ),
        iMessageSize ( 0 ),
        iOriginalMessageSize ( 0 ),
        iFragmentID( 0 ),
        iTotalPayloadLength( 0 ),
        iBytesComplete( 0 ),
        iAccumulatedMsgLength ( 0 ),
        iRemainder ( 0 ),
        iStartOfRemainder( 0 ),
        iTotalMsgLoad ( 0 )
    {
    }

    SFrame(const SFrame &c_rSrc)
    {
        *this = c_rSrc;
    }

    SFrame &SFrame::operator=(const SFrame &c_rSrc)
    {
        iIP_Header_Length = c_rSrc.iIP_Header_Length;
        iTCP_Header_Length = c_rSrc.iTCP_Header_Length;
        iTCP_Source_Port = c_rSrc.iTCP_Source_Port;
        iTCP_Dest_Port = c_rSrc.iTCP_Dest_Port;
        iIp_total_length = c_rSrc.iIp_total_length;
        iActual_frame_length = c_rSrc.iActual_frame_length;
        iOriginal_frame_length = c_rSrc.iOriginal_frame_length;
        iCaptured_frame_length = c_rSrc.iCaptured_frame_length;
        iPayloadLength = c_rSrc.iPayloadLength;
        uiSequenceNumber = c_rSrc.uiSequenceNumber;
        uiInitialSequenceNumber = c_rSrc.uiInitialSequenceNumber;
        uiAckNumber = c_rSrc.uiAckNumber;
        iNextExpectedSequenceNum = c_rSrc.iNextExpectedSequenceNum;
        uiClientID = c_rSrc.uiClientID;
        iFragmentID = c_rSrc.iFragmentID;
        iMessageSize = c_rSrc.iMessageSize;
        iOriginalMessageSize = c_rSrc.iOriginalMessageSize;
        iTotalPayloadLength = c_rSrc.iTotalPayloadLength;
        iBytesComplete = c_rSrc.iBytesComplete;
        iAccumulatedMsgLength = c_rSrc.iAccumulatedMsgLength;
        iRemainder = c_rSrc.iRemainder;
        iStartOfRemainder = c_rSrc.iStartOfRemainder;
        iTotalMsgLoad = c_rSrc.iTotalMsgLoad;

        strSourceAddress = c_rSrc.strSourceAddress;
        strDestAddress = c_rSrc.strDestAddress;
        strTimestamp = c_rSrc.strTimestamp;

        pszMessage = (c_rSrc.pszMessage == NULL) ? NULL : new unsigned char[c_rSrc.iMessageSize];
        pszOriginalMessage = (c_rSrc.pszOriginalMessage == NULL) ? NULL : new unsigned char[c_rSrc.iOriginalMessageSize];

        if(pszMessage != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(pszMessage, c_rSrc.pszMessage, c_rSrc.iMessageSize);
        }


        if(pszOriginalMessage != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(pszOriginalMessage, c_rSrc.pszOriginalMessage, c_rSrc.iOriginalMessageSize);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~SFrame()
    {
        delete [] pszMessage;
        delete [] pszOriginalMessage;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are those members pointers instead of `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/f/idjwk2pEp

Comment: Which members Paul?...

Comment: http://imageshack.com/f/exSaUdG3p <- this is after i delete the array...

Comment: Do you clear the `pszMessage` pointer after calling `ClearMemory` to avoid freeing twice? Otherwise all I can think of is that you have a buffer overflow somewhere. `delete[]` isn't broken.

Comment: These members: `m_sFrame.pszMessage`             `m_sFrame.pszOriginalMessage`  It would also help if you posted what `SFrame` is.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I do ClearMemory then come round the next iteration, i do m_sFrame = SFrame() which calls the copy constructor and I do something like this:

if (pszMessage != NULL)
memcpy(pszMessage, c_rSrc.pszMessage, c_rSrc.iMessageSize), where c_rSrc is the parameter in the copy constructor.... I don't think i'm calling anything after ClearMemory for that iteration.

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - If you used `vector`, all your problems will more than likely go away.

Comment: Vector for what? storing my data? I'll post SFrame - but i warn, it's quite large...

Comment: @PatriciaAydin Yes.  Instead of `unsigned char *`, use `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: In many places I'm doing something like:

sFrame.pszMessage = new unsigned char[sFrame.iAccumulatedMsgLength + iExtFlag];
memcpy(sFrame.pszMessage, &sFrame.pszOriginalMessage[sFrame.iBytesComplete], sFrame.iAccumulatedMsgLength + iExtFlag);

How would I rewrite all of my memcpys using a vector<unsigned char>?

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - Using vector would cut that code in half.  You're using `vector` now -- were you not aware of the practical uses for `vector`, namely replacing that error-prone pointer handling with a safe container?

Comment: PS: Do you know what might be causing the corruption in my current implementation? I've checked every byte and i haven't got my numbers wrong... the amount i'm copying and deleting is the correct number, however i don't understand why it seems that delete [] pszMessage is clearing more than i have allocated...

Comment: I've used vectors for many things, but i'm not used to using it for buffers... could you write an example of how it would be written using the example above? I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to buffer/memory etc

Comment: @PatriciaAydin As someone else pointed out, `delete[]` is not broken.  What is probably broken is you mishandling pointers.  Again, drop the pointers and use vector.  Having said that, what are these members used for? `int* ipTemp_int_ptr;    int* ipTemp_int_ptr_actual;
    int* piTimestampPos;    int* piOffset;`  Are they also "dynamic arrays"?  If they are, again, *use vector*.

Comment: Indeed they are... so just change "unsigned char*" to vector... Will try and figure out how to write it as a vector...

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - The problem you're having is that your struct does not follow the "Rule of 3" (copying an SFrame to another SFrame is not safe since you're missing a user defined copy constructor and assingment operator), all due to the pointer members.  The `vector<SFrame>` is going to make copies, and your struct is not safely copyable.  THat's the gist of the problem.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. However, I'm trying to think of a "simple" solution. There's alot of complex code happening in the core of it all and I didn't really want to change the way it works. Can't really think of a solution where the Struct safely copies itself....

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - The problem is that it doesn't work.  It won't work regardless until you add a copy constructor and assignment operator, *or* change to `vector` and just fix the compiler errors once that's done.  The latter is a lot easier than you think.

Comment: I wish I did find it easy but I honestly can't think how to write it... I know it will be an std::vector<unsigned char> pszMessage for example... but I guess i will also have to manually keep hold of the size. I can't use size(), because it is binary so there will be null values where I wouldn't want the vector to stop counting...

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - I see the copy constructor and assignment operator.  You see how many members you have?  If you miss just one, or the memory isn't allocated/deallocated properly, you have a broken copy.  I will post the answer using vector.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul :) yeah I thought it would be neat using a copy constructor but really... So many variables to keep account of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `SFrame` struct is not safely asignable, yet you are placing instances of this in a `std::vector` that will make copies.

Either:

1. Add a *working* user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator to your `SFrame` struct or
2. Replace the pointer members with `std::vector`.

You have many members in your struct now.  If you miss just one in your copy constructor, or your handling of allocated memory is faulty, you will have a broken copy.  Since a `vector<SFrame>` will create copies, having broken copies is a no-go with `vector<SFrame>`.

So instead of this, here is the fix using option 2:

```
#include <vector>
struct SFrame
{
    std::vector<int> ipTemp_int_ptr;
    std::vector<int> ipTemp_int_ptr_actual;
    std::vector<int> piTimestampPos;
    std::vector<int> piOffset;
    int iIP_Header_Length;
    int iTCP_Header_Length;
    int iTCP_Source_Port;
    int iTCP_Dest_Port;
    long long uiSequenceNumber;
    long long uiInitialSequenceNumber;
    long long uiAckNumber;
    int iIp_total_length;
    int iActual_frame_length;
    int iOriginal_frame_length;
    int iCaptured_frame_length;
    int iTotalPayloadLength;
    int iTotalMsgLoad;
    int iPayloadLength;
    int iBytesComplete;
    int iFragmentID;
    int iRemainder;
    int iMessageSize;
    int iOriginalMessageSize;
    long long iNextExpectedSequenceNum;
    std::string strSourceAddress;
    std::string strDestAddress;
    std::string strTimestamp;
    std::vector<unsigned char> pszMessage;
    std::vector<unsigned char> pszOriginalMessage;
    unsigned int uiClientID;
    int iStartOfRemainder;
    int iAccumulatedMsgLength;

    SFrame() : 
        iIP_Header_Length( 0 ),
        iTCP_Header_Length ( 0 ),
        iTCP_Source_Port ( 0 ),
        iTCP_Dest_Port ( 0 ),
        iIp_total_length ( 0 ),
        iActual_frame_length ( 0 ),
        iOriginal_frame_length ( 0 ),
        iCaptured_frame_length ( 0 ),
        uiSequenceNumber( 0 ),
        uiInitialSequenceNumber ( 0 ),
        uiAckNumber( 0 ),
        iPayloadLength ( 0 ),
        iNextExpectedSequenceNum ( 0 ),
        uiClientID ( 0 ),
        iMessageSize ( 0 ),
        iOriginalMessageSize ( 0 ),
        iFragmentID( 0 ),
        iTotalPayloadLength( 0 ),
        iBytesComplete( 0 ),
        iAccumulatedMsgLength ( 0 ),
        iRemainder ( 0 ),
        iStartOfRemainder( 0 ),
        iTotalMsgLoad ( 0 )
    {
    }
};
```

Note that the copy constructor and assignment operator (and destructor) are now gone, thus making the code a lot easier to handle, as well as not having a chance of missing any of the members during the copy.  Instead we let the compiler generate the copy, and the compiler will *always* get every member copied.

Now, your code base that uses the struct has to be recompiled, and you will inevitably get compiler errors.  However those errors are usually very easy to fix.  Most will probably require you to

1. Remove the lines with `delete [] somepointer;` where `somePointer` is now a vector and
2. If passing a pointer to the beginning of the buffer, you pass `&vector[0]` or `vector.data()`, since a vector is basically a wrapper for `new[]/delete[]`.

Going back to your original code, one issue with your assignment operator is that you failed to delete the previous memory allocated, thus you have a memory leak.  Also, you didn't check for self-assignment, given the way you wrote the copy operations.  However, this may not have been the only error, as we didn't see how you're using these `SFrame` instances.

Therefore it may be better to change to vector, fix the compiler errors, rebuild and test your app.

Comment: What if I wished to add some data in a certain position of the vector? And I should manually keep track of the size right? There will be null values in the block of data but will need the size of the whole block.

Comment: @PatriciaAydin Use `vector::insert`.

Comment: But determining the size? Would myvector.size() give me back the size of the block even though it has null terminated characters? Or is that how vector determines the size. If so I'll just keep manual sizes like what I already do

Comment: @PatriciaAydin - The vector knows its own size by using the `size()` member.  There is no need to tag along a variable to denote the size.